# importing an class from the same directory in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, oop

i have a directory with main.pl and Product.pl. in the main.pl i try to import the Product class but the execution fails when i run perl main.pl complaining that cant locate Product.pm in @INC. My directory is not in the @INC list. How can i fix this?

Comment: The duplicate question's answers don't really answer this, so my answer is to use [lib::relative](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib::relative) or the mechanism described in its docs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a local subdirectory, name it `lib` and put your module file there. On newer Perls you must tell Perl to include that local directory to `@INC`, either by adding it to `PERL5LIB` (environment variable) somehow, or by adding

```
use lib qw( . );
```

to the script that wants to load that module. If you are paranoid you can also use an absolute path.

Comment: No, they want the script's directory, not the CWD.

Answer (score 0):

You already got some help in *complain* that module's filename should end in `.pm`. Now you need to look for the purpose of variable `PERL5LIB=???`.

[PERL5LIB](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)